# Hide all Visual Studio toolbars?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, hide, toolbar

I generally (there are exceptions) don't use toolbars in VS.  It keeps happening that I'll open a new filetype (XML, HTML, SQL, ASPX, CS, etc, etc) and have to manually hide the "new" toolbar(s).

Can I hide all toolbars in Visual Studio 2010 in one action?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.This does not remove the new toolbars, just maximizes your code window ineffect hiding all but the file toolbar.

Comment: Full Screen isn't a good match for me, as it removes all tool _panes_ as well.

Comment: @lance: in that case, you will have to get back the tool panes you want selectively. Ctrl+Alt+L for Solution Explorer, F4 for properties, Ctrl+\,Ctrl+M for Team Explorer, Ctrl+Alt+X for toolbox etc. The good thing is you can pin them even in full screen mode. Now, if you were able to save you ideal screen as a 'perspective', like in Eclipse, that would have been nice!

Comment: also, as a bonus, you can download the [Hide Main Menu](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813?SRC=VSIDE) VS extension (i just installed it yesterday and it works well) to hide even the File Menu toolbar.

Answer (score 7):

You might like the [Hide Main Menu extension from Microsoft](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813) that hides the menu bar like in IE. And of course use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> for full screen and re-create all the needed panes. Visual Studio will remember the panes settings the next time you switch to the full screen mode.

Comment: I _do_ like that extension. I use it daily. Thank you for sharing it here.

Comment: note: updated extension for VS 2017 can be found here: http://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.com/2017/05/hide-main-menu-for-visual-studio-2017.html

Answer (score 4):

Full Screen Mode is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, this removes much of the stuff you don't want.

Comment: Full Screen isn't a good match for me, as it removes all tool _panes_ as well.